Do a stochastic process and its integral over time generates the same filtration
Suppose $X$ is a jointly measurable process that such that almost surely, for all $t\geq 0$, $\int_0^t|X_s|\mathrm{d}s<\infty$, and define the integral process $Y_t=\int_0^tX_s\mathrm{d}s$. Are $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(X_s:0\leq s\leq t)$ and $\mathcal{G}_t=\sigma(Y_s:0\leq s\leq t)$ the same in general?
I know $Y_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable, so $\mathcal{G}_t\subset\mathcal{F}_t$.
What about the other inclusion? I know for every path of $Y$, its derivative is $X$ at almost every $t$, so one can get $X_t=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{Y_t-Y_{t-q_n}}{q_n}$ where $\{q_n\}$ is a sequence of rationals decreasing to zero. However, this does not work for every $t$ and moreover, for a different path, the set of $t$ that works may be different.
Any idea on this? Thanks!

The answer seems to me to be no in general, at least for cadlag processes. If $X$ is a jump from $0$ to $1$ at a stopping time $\tau$ which may take any nonnegative value, then it is not possible to find a measurable functional $f$ such that $X_t=f((Y_s)_{s\leq t})$  - for any fixed $t$. Indeed, suppose this were possible. Fix $t$. Consider $\omega \in \{\tau=t\}$. Then $1=X_t(\omega)=f(0)$ (because $Y_s(\omega)=0$ for all $s\leq t$). Now consider $\omega\in\{\tau=t+\varepsilon\}$. Then $0=X_t(\omega)=f(0)$, which is absurd. So we have that $X_t$ is not $\mathscr{G}_t$-measurable.

Nice example, thanks

@Snoop Nice argument. A technical point bothers me, though. What does it mean exactly to be a Borel function of the whole process $Y_s$ up to time $t$? If it was just one or finitely many random variables, I would understand.

@Weltschmerz it means a functional mapping the path space (the space of cadlag functions) to $\mathbb{R}$. The path space is Polish under the standard Skorokhod topology and we have a Borel sigma algebra on it.

The integral process $Y$ does not notice changes in the path of $X$ at any finite or countable number of points. Using this, it's easy to construct examples where $X$ carries more information than $Y$.
For example, let $\mathcal{P}$ be the points of a Poisson process of rate $1$; then let $X_t=1$ for $t\in\mathcal{P}$ and $X_t=0$ otherwise. Then with probability $1$, $Y_t=0$ for all $t$. So $\mathcal{F}_t$ carries information about the points of $\mathcal{P}$ in $[0,t]$, and $\mathcal{G}_t$ does not.
Similarly, let $X_t=0$ for all $t>0$, and let $X_0$ have, say, Exponential($1)$ distribution (or, indeed, any other non-constant distribution). Again $Y$ is $0$ everywhere.
Indeed, for any case where the distribution of $X_0$ is not constant, $\mathcal{F}_0$ tells you the value of $X_0$ and $\mathcal{G}_0$ does not.
If you add the condition that $X$ is continuous, I think your property holds for all strictly positive $t$. You can obtain the value of $X_u$ from $\mathcal{G}_t$ for any $0<u\leq t$ by considering $X_u=\lim_{h\to 0}(Y_{u}-Y_{u-h})/h$.
For cadlag processes, as considered in Snoop's answer, you might get something close to your property, but slightly weaker, such as $\mathcal{G}_t\subseteq \mathcal{F}_t\subseteq \bigcap_{u>t} \mathcal{G}_u$.

Thanks for your nice answer. Sorry I can pick only one
